# An unexpected result when using make4ht+mathjax-node-page

Tags: make4ht

I exactly follow the instruction from [latex mathjax node](https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/mathjaxnode/maths.html) but getting some unexpected result, first in section 6 accents, the math symbols are not corrected,
[image]
second, in HTML some information is missing [image]
in pdf file, it should be
[image]
third, in theorem environment, some font in the HTML file looks like too big.
[image]

Here is my error message when I run make4ht

```
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: maths.tex
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
--- warning --- \special{t4ht~...} without \special{t4ht~}
[WARNING] domfilter: DOM parsing of maths.html failed:
[WARNING] domfilter: ...ive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaxml/luaxml-mod-xml.lua:175: Unbalanced Tag (/msup) [char=37676]

Formula <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block" class="equation">
      <msub><mrow><mi>u</mi></mrow><mrow><mn>1</mn></mrow></msub> <mo class="MathClass-rel">=</mo> <!--l. 216--><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="inline"><mrow>−2γ</mrow><mrow>2</mrow>s<mrow>2</mrow>+μ<mrow>3</mrow><mstyle mathsize="1.19em"><mfenced separators="" open="("><mrow></mrow></mfenced></mstyle><mfrac><mrow>3</mrow>
<mrow>8</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>2</mrow>+<mfrac><mrow>1</mrow>
<mrow>8</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>1</mrow>i<mstyle mathsize="1.19em"><mfenced separators="" open=")"><mrow></mrow></mfenced></mstyle>+<mrow>3</mrow><mstyle mathsize="1.19em"><mfenced separators="" open="("><mrow></mrow></mfenced></mstyle>−<mfrac><mrow>81</mrow>
<mrow>32</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>4</mrow>s<mrow>2</mrow><mrow>2</mrow>−<mfrac><mrow>27</mrow>
<mrow>16</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>4</mrow>s<mrow>2</mrow>s<mrow>1</mrow>i+ <mfrac><mrow>9</mrow>
<mrow>32</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>4</mrow>s<mrow>1</mrow><mrow>2</mrow>+<mfrac><mrow>27</mrow>
<mrow>32</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>3</mrow>s<mrow>2</mrow><mrow>2</mrow>i−<mfrac><mrow>9</mrow>
<mrow>16</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>3</mrow>s<mrow>2</mrow>s<mrow>1</mrow>−<mfrac><mrow>3</mrow>
<mrow>32</mrow></mfrac>s<mrow>3</mrow>s<mrow>1</mrow><mrow>2</mrow>i<mstyle mathsize="1.19em"><mfenced separators="" open=")"><mrow></mrow></mfenced></mstyle>+∫<!--nolimits--><!--nolimits--><mrow>
a</mrow><mrow>b</mrow>1−2x+3x<mrow>2</mrow>−4x<mrow>3</mrow><mspace width="0.3em" class="thinspace"></mspace>dx</math>
</math> contains the following errors:
 [ 'MathML - Unexpected text node: \'−2γ\'' ]
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

### I use texlive2019, so how to fix all the questions above?

maths.tex file is  [here](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/anthony.roberts/LaTeX/Src/maths.tex)

stack.cfg file is as below

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,fn-in,html5}  
\Css{body{  
    margin:40px auto;  
    max-width:36em;  
    line-height:1.6;  
    font-size:1em; 0.88em;  
    color:\#222;  
    background-color:\#FEFEF7;  
    padding:0 10px;}}  
\Css{h1,h2,h3{line-height:1.2}}  
\Css{p.indent{text-indent:0;}}  
\Css{@media (min-width: 29.63em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 3vw;  
  }  
}}  

\Css{@media (min-width: 40.74em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 1.375em;  
  }  
}}  
\Css{body {  
font-family: STIXGeneral, "Linux Libertine O", Gentium, Georgia,  
"Times New Roman",  "Iowan Old Style",  
 Palatino Linotype, Palatino, serif;  
}}  
\begin{document}  
\EndPreamble
```

and then I use this command

> make4ht -uf html5+mathjaxnode -c stack.cfg maths.tex

Comment: Hi, I willl need some LaTeX code to test

Comment: don't make an external link, your question is archived forever but that dropbox link will break, make a small self contained example and add it to the question in a code block.

Comment: @michal.h21 I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is caused by the `\parmath` command, which is defined in the document text, so it cannot be patched from the configuration file. It looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\parmath}[2][0.8\linewidth]{\parbox[t]{#1}%
{\raggedright\linespread{1.2}\selectfont\(#2\)}}
```

The explicit nested math commands seems to explode the MathML code.
I would redefine it in the following way:

```
\newcommand{\parmath}[2][0.8\linewidth]{\parbox[t]{#1}%
{\raggedright\linespread{1.2}\selectfont\ensuremath{#2}}}
```

It uses `\ensuremath` instead of `\( ... \)`, which works better in such cases.

I've also found issue with accents that results in error message instead of rendered MathML code. I've fix that in `tex4ht` sources, but before this fix arrives in the TeX distributions, you can use the updated configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,fn-in,html5}  
\Css{body{  
    margin:40px auto;  
    max-width:36em;  
    line-height:1.6;  
    font-size:1em; 0.88em;  
    color:\#222;  
    background-color:\#FEFEF7;  
    padding:0 10px;}}  
\Css{h1,h2,h3{line-height:1.2}}  
\Css{p.indent{text-indent:0;}}  
\Css{@media (min-width: 29.63em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 3vw;  
  }  
}}  

\Css{@media (min-width: 40.74em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 1.375em;  
  }  
}}  


\Css{body {  
font-family: STIXGeneral, "Linux Libertine O", Gentium, Georgia,  
"Times New Roman",  "Iowan Old Style",  
 Palatino Linotype, Palatino, serif;  
}}  
\begin{document}  
\catcode`\:=11

\def\myop#1{\PauseMathClass\HCode{<mo accent="true">}#1\HCode{</mo>}\EndPauseMathClass}
\def\:vec:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{2192}}}
\def\:grave:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0300}}}
\def\:acute:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0301}}}
\def\:hat:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0302}}}
\def\:widehat:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0302}}}
\def\:tilde:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0303}}}
\def\:widetilde:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0303}}}
\def\:bar:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0304}}}
\def\:breve:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0306}}}
\def\:dot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0307}}}
\def\:ddot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0308}}}
\def\:uml:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0308}}}
\def\:ring:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030A}}}
\def\:Huml:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030B}}}
\def\:check:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030C}}}
\def\:d:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0323}}}
\def\:cedil:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0327}}}
\def\:b:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0331}}}
\def\:udot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0361}}}

\catcode`\:=12
\EndPreamble
```

This is the rendered problematic part with the fix:

[image]