# A still unexpected result when using make4ht+mathjax-node-page

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I have asked a question here [old question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522059/an-unexpected-result-when-using-make4htmathjax-node-page/522150#522150), and I exactly follow the answer, now accent problem has been solved, but there are still some bugs. Here is my html, I have converted it to pictures.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
I think there are some bugs in default CSS setting of tex4ht or make4ht. Hope someone can fix them. I use texlive 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this seems like a lot of issues :) I've updated TeX4ht sources with most of the fixes presented here, so they should become unnecessary soon. Some issues were fixed also in `make4ht`, so you will need the [development version](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht).

Issue 1 - huge text.

It is caused by the `extarticle` class, because the document selects font size of 20pt as the base font size. TeX4ht can detect the font sizes and produce CSS instructions to use these sizes in the document. In this case we obviously don't want that.

To fix that, use the following version of `extarticle.4ht`:

```
\ifnum\@ptsize>12\relax
\renewcommand\@ptsize{10}
\input{size\@ptsize.clo}
\fi
\Hinput{extarticle}
\endinput
```

The size of `\verb` command will be fixed in the config file

Issue 2 - size of integrals

This was bug in TeX4ht, it generated wrong MathML structure.

Issue 3 - non-italic math text

Bug in `make4ht`, it should be fixed by the development version.

Issue 4 - missing `\boldsymbol` support

It should be supported now.

Note that some issues can be also caused by different rendering of MathML in contrast to TeX, it isn't always the same. I've noticed that for example the multi-line code in section 7 is broken to lines by Firefox, but it remains on one line when rendered by MathJax.

Here is the updated config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,fn-in,html5}  
\Css{body{  
    margin:40px auto;  
    max-width:36em;  
    line-height:1.6;  
    font-size:1em; 0.88em;  
    color:\#222;  
    background-color:\#FEFEF7;  
    padding:0 10px;}}  
\Css{h1,h2,h3{line-height:1.2}}  
\Css{p.indent{text-indent:0;}}  
\Css{@media (min-width: 29.63em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 3vw;  
  }  
}}  

\Css{@media (min-width: 40.74em){  
  :root {  
    font-size: 1.375em;  
  }  
}}  




\Css{body {  
font-family: STIXGeneral, "Linux Libertine O", Gentium, Georgia,  
"Times New Roman",  "Iowan Old Style",  
 Palatino Linotype, Palatino, serif;  
}}  

\Configure{verb}{\NoFonts\HCode{<code>}}{\HCode{</code>}\EndNoFonts}
%\Css{code{font-family:monospace,monospace}}
\begin{document}  
\catcode`\:=11

\def\myop#1{\PauseMathClass\HCode{<mo accent="true">}#1\HCode{</mo>}\EndPauseMathClass}
\def\:vec:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{2192}}}
\def\:grave:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0300}}}
\def\:acute:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0301}}}
\def\:hat:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0302}}}
\def\:widehat:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0302}}}
\def\:tilde:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0303}}}
\def\:widetilde:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0303}}}
\def\:bar:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0304}}}
\def\:breve:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0306}}}
\def\:dot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0307}}}
\def\:ddot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0308}}}
\def\:uml:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0308}}}
\def\:ring:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030A}}}
\def\:Huml:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030B}}}
\def\:check:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{030C}}}
\def\:d:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0323}}}
\def\:cedil:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0327}}}
\def\:b:under{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0331}}}
\def\:udot:over{\ifmmode\expandafter\myop\fi{\x:unicode{0361}}}


% handle integrals
\def\:tempc{\ifDisplayMath\mathop:prefix{largeop="true"}\fi\o:n:int::}
\HLet\n:int:\:tempc


\renewcommand\boldsymbol[1]{\HCode{<mstyle class="boldsymbol" mathvariant="bold-italic">}#1\HCode{</mstyle>}}

\def\mathop:prefix#1{%
   \Configure{mathop}{*}{<\a:mathml mo #1\Hnewline>}{</\a:mathml mo>}%
    {\Configure{mathop}{*}{<\a:mathml mo>}{</\a:mathml mo>}{}}}
\catcode`\:=12
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

[image]

[image]